# How to fix SwiftUI picker not displaying horizontally centered?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-picker

I created a simple Picker like so:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let options = ["Action", "Comedy", "Drama", "Horror", "Zombie"]
    @State var selection = "Action"
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select Genre", selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(options, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text(item)
                        Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

[image]

When it displays I can see that it is slightly left aligned in the screen. Is there any way to fix this? Also, is there any way to detect when the Picker is showing its options?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer to both is no, unless you change the picker style to something like `.wheel`.

Comment: That's too bad :( Hopefully it is fixed in future releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options menu moves with the `Picker`, so by adding padding to the `Picker` you can center it. But then, the `Picker` itself is a bit off-center. You could mask this by showing the same `Picker` as an overlay, without the padding. If you apply `.allowsHitTesting(false)` to the overlay then it becomes inactive, so when you tap it, the tap passes through and you get the menu from the base `Picker`.

This kind of workaround may break if the layout changes in a future iOS version. So I would only suggest using it for iOS versions that you have actually tested.

Like this:

```swift
private var thePicker: some View {
    Picker("Select Genre", selection: $selection) {
        ForEach(options, id: \.self) { item in
            HStack {
                Text(item)
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
            }
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        if #available(iOS 17.3, *) {
            thePicker
        } else if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
            thePicker
                .padding(.leading, 16)
                .overlay {
                    thePicker
                        .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                        .allowsHitTesting(false)
                }
        } else {
            thePicker
        }
    }
    .padding()
}
```

[image: Screenshot]